# openapi codegen without access methods

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using the openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate model sources.

Is there a way to generate them only with fields and without any access methods?
I want the access methods to be generated via lombok with the additionalModelTypeAnnotations configOption in the maven configuration of the openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can implement those customizations by changing the [Mustache templates](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating/)

Fetch the templates of the Java framework (ie spring-boot) you want to use (ie `openapi-generator-cli author template -g spring --additional-properties=library=spring-boot -o tmp/mytemplates`

Modify the local `model.mustache` file to import the packages you want (lombok) and `pojo.mustache` to remove the getters/setters. There might other customisations necessary (each framework templates are different) but this the recommended approach.

Answer (score 1):

As @beppe suggested in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75377159/6860078), this can easily be done by modifying the mustache template.  However, I highly advice against it.  In doing so, you discard many of the the features included with the model objects created by the generator.  Some of the features you lose are:

- Bean Validation
- Jackson Serialization Library Support
- [Support for vendor extensions](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/java.md#supported-vendor-extensions)

By adding the `Lombok` annotation to the generated files, you are basically ignoring the main point of the generator, which is to generate files that support each other.  You are instead using a generator to call a generator.

Finally, the amount of customization necessary to make the lombok library work with the mustache files is much more than is really worth it.  Sure, you can add `@Data` or `@Jacksonized` to your model, but what about `@JsonIgnore`?  Do you want to use parameters in your Lombok calls?  Because you can't set the builder classname via `@Builder(builderClassName = "EmployeeBuilder")`.  That would be hardcoded.  Instead, you'd have to use mustache parameters, such as `@Builder(builderClassName = {{$builderClassName}})`, which you'd then have to define elsewhere.  What about `@Builder` vs `@SuperBuilder`?  Which one do you use in which situation?  How do you define and template it?

At this point, you might as well rewrite the entire `pojo.mustache` to be able to use the lombok annotations.  But, what if you need the old `pojo.mustache` functionality elsewhere?  Now you need to write a custom generator to determine which mustache to use in which situations.

It is best to just build the domain models as the `openapi-generator` intends and use them as they are.  You can add annotations if you need to via vendor extensions such as `x-field-extra-annotation` and `x-class-extra-annotation` if you really feel the need to.